# Android: Restrict a user from swiping screens in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a Tabbed Activity: a user can swipe to the right or to the left to change the screens. At some point I want to record an audio and while it is being recorder the user is not supposed to change the screens.

**Question:** How to restrict a user from changing screens (swiping) in `ViewPager`?

I tried to figure out how to do that using `ViewPager` API but I didn't manage to find a proper way (there are hundreds or may be even thousand methods in `ViewPager` none of which is likely to do what I want).

Comment: Why voting down? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the ViewPager class and use this code.

```
public class LockableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean swipeable;

    public LockableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LockableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.swipeable = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.swipeable && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.swipeable && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable) {
        this.swipeable = swipeable;
    }
}
```

Then in your Fragment or Activity you can just call `mViewPager.setSwipeable(false);` to make it unswipeable.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I also simplified your code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom viewPager like below

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        if (enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Then simply call `viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);`

Comment: Thank you. I’ll try out tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: setPagingEnabled is not a valid method you can call on a ViewPager. Please see the official Android doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager

Comment: Yes, I was about to add the custom view pager class, because of internet connectivity it didn't reflect